# Can I ellipsize a dialog title?

Tags: android, dialog, title

I have an Activity running as a Theme.Dialog. Can I set its title to an "ellipsize" style? Currently, the text is being populated in onCreate() with setText(). There's no this.setEllipsize() like on TextView.

Or, is my only option to write [a Custom Dialog](http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/) and set the title style there? I'd like to know if that's possible before heading down that path.

Comment: Could you pass the title to the dialog already ellipsized?

Comment: Sure, but then I'd have to do something like calculate the width of the dialog box for various Android screens, no?

I calculate the maximum number of characters a screen could show, then ellipsize the final 3 characters to dots.

Answer (score 5):

Clean & easy without any custom views:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

Comment: Have just used this code in an app running on a Nexus7 with Android 4.3. It works, BUT sometimes I got some characters after the ellipsis in the dialog title. This is most probably another case of [Issue 882](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882), #9 there has a workaround: `tv.setLines(1);tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);` Helped me here as well. Now everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The following code help you to ellipsize the textview...

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCustomTitle(GetDialogTitleView(this,R.string.TitleStr));

private static TextView GetDialogTitleView(Context mContext,int TitleResID)
    {

        TextView title = new TextView(mContext);
        title.setText(TitleResID);
        title.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        title.setPadding(5, 5, 5,5);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        TruncateAt ta = TruncateAt.MIDDLE;
        title.setEllipsize(ta);
        title.setTextSize(20);
        return title;
    }
```